# chmod does not change file permissions

Tags: chmod

I am trying to create an executable "Hello World" ruby file and I copied an existing, working executable "Hello World" ruby file and renamed it, but the new file does not have any executable permissions.  The original file had the following permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1
```

The new file has the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1
```

I have tried `chmod -x [Filename]` for the new file as well as `sudo chmod`, but nothing changes the file permissions. The file permissions remain:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1
```

Any attempt to execute the file understandably returns

> bash: [filename]: Permission_denied

Comment: The file could be immutable. You can remove this attribute with `chattr`. The immutable attribute would also prevent the super user from modifying the file.

Comment: Or the driver for the file system (eg. ntfs-3g) may not support file permissions.

Answer (score 7):

The command `chmod -x [Filename]` **removes** the executable permission from the file you are attempting to execute. If you wanted to make the file executable, you want to try something like `chmod +x [Filename]` (notice the + in place of minus).